# VBA: Make every 20th cell bold

Tags: excel, vba

I have a loop that puts bold font on every 10th entry in an Excel sheet, however I want bold font on every 20th entry. How can I fix this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
'insert xxxx9 after xxxx8 if needed
For i = 3 To counter - 1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value Mod 10 = 8 Then
   ' counter = counter + 1
        If Cells(i + 1, 1) <> Cells(i, 1) + 1 Then

            i = i + 1
            Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

            Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) + 1
            Range("A" & 20).Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            Cells(i, 2) = "900"
            Range("B" & i).Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            Cells(i, 3) = "chk"
            Range("C" & i).Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            Cells(i, 6) = "1"
            Range("F" & i).Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
        Else
            i = i + 1
            Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
            Range("A" & i).Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    End If
Next


 'count number of entries
counter = 2
While (Cells(counter, 1).Value <> "" Or Cells(counter, 1).Value <> Null)
    counter = counter + 1
Wend

 'insert xxxx9 after xxxx8 if needed
For i = 3 To counter - 1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value Mod 10 = 8 Then
   ' counter = counter + 1
        If Cells(i + 1, 1) <> Cells(i, 1) + 1 Then

            i = i + 1
            Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

            Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) + 1
            Range("A" & 20).Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            Cells(i, 2) = "900"
            Range("B" & i).Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            Cells(i, 3) = "chk"
            Range("C" & i).Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            Cells(i, 6) = "1"
            Range("F" & i).Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
        Else
            i = i + 1
            Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
            Range("A" & i).Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Change the way the `for ... next` iterates like `For i = 3 To counter - 1 Step 20` . This will speed up the routine by removing the necessity to check you are on the correct row.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That worked in a way, but it now stopped putting a bold on the 20th entry too.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, but it looks like you're selecting every 10th row for processing--that is, it looks like you expect the first column to contain sequential numbers, and so `If Cells(i, 1).Value Mod 10 = 8` selects rows with values of 8, 18, 28, etc. This might explain why the suggestion of @Jeeped caused the bolding to stop. I think you need to explain your objective better in order to get good assistance.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Yes! i had to change the Cells(i, 1).Value Mod 10 = 8 to Cells(i, 1).Value Mod 20 = 18

Answer (score 0):

Mod 10 is returning the remainder after dividing by 10. To get the condition to be TRUE only once every 20 rows, use Mod 20 instead. Adjust what it is equal accordingly to ensure it starts in the correct location.